# Detect that window content is rendered by DirectX

Tags: winapi, directx

I am trying to make window screenshot tool that can grab windows hidden in background. I know only one way to do this - through PrintWindow function, [which fails for DirectX windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682228/troubleshoot-why-printwindow-is-blank/30691667). So is it possible to detect that the window is rendered by DirectX and fail early?

Comment: That's not the only way to make a screenshot. Wouldn't it be better to find a better screenshot method?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, well I will appreciate if you can tell me how to make screenshot of DirectX window that has another window with focus on top of that without disrupting the flow.

Comment: Well, nobody can do that here since it's not the question you asked.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε windows (vista in my case)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, asked new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694056/make-screenshot-of-directx-window-that-is-hidden-or-doesnt-have-focus

Comment: You can show a live thumbnail of the the hidden window in another one with `DwmRegisterThumbnail` and `DwmUpdateThumbnailProperties`. I dont know if that is enough.